# PHP Print Nested Category Array

Tags: php, arrays, nested

Array is this:

```
array (
  'id' => 10,
  'name' => 'category 1',
  'children' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 11,
      'name' => 'category 1 child',
      'children' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 17,
          'name' => 'category 1 grandchild',
          'children' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'id' => 19,
              'name' => 'category 1 great-grandchild',
              'children' => 
              array (
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'id' => 20,
          'name' => 'category 1 grandchild 2',
          'children' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 18,
      'name' => 'category 1 child 2',
      'children' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 21,
          'name' => 'category 1 child 2 grandchild',
          'children' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

And this:

```
array (
  'id' => 12,
  'name' => 'category 2',
  'children' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 13,
      'name' => 'category 2 child',
      'children' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 15,
          'name' => 'category 2 grandchild',
          'children' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'id' => 16,
              'name' => 'category 2 great-grandchild',
              'children' => 
              array (
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 22,
      'name' => 'category 2 child 2',
      'children' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 23,
          'name' => 'category 2 child 2 grandchild',
          'children' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'id' => 24,
          'name' => 'category 2 child 2 grandchild 2',
          'children' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Need to print out as nested `<ul><li>`, so far almost achieved with this:

```
function printCategory($category, $html='', $space=0, $test=false) {
        \Log::info($category);
        if (count($category['children']) > 0) {
            $html .= '<ul>';
            $html .= '<li>' . $category['name'] . '</li>';

            foreach ($category['children'] as $c) {
                $space++;
                $html = printCategory($c, $html, $space, true);
            }

            if ($test === false) {
                $space += count($category['children']);
                for ($i=0; $i<$space; $i++) {
                    $html .= '</ul>';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $html .= '<ul>';
            $html .= '<li>' . $category['name'] . '</li>';
            for ($i=0; $i<$space; $i++) {
                $html .= '</ul>';
                $space--;
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }
```

Which produce this:

```
<li>category 1</li><ul><li>category 1 child</li><ul><li>category 1 grandchild</li><ul><li>category 1 great-grandchild</li></ul></ul><ul><li>category 1 grandchild 2</li></ul></ul><ul><li>category 1 child 2</li><ul><li>category 1 child 2 grandchild</li></ul></ul>
<li>category 2</li><ul><li>category 2 child</li><ul><li>category 2 grandchild</li><ul><li>category 2 great-grandchild</li></ul></ul><ul><li>category 2 child 2</li><ul><li>category 2 child 2 grandchild</li></ul></ul><ul><li>category 2 child 2 grandchild 2</li></ul></ul>
```

Which technically almost correct except for `category 2 child 2 grandchild 2` which is off [image]

See image, suppose to be under `category 2 child 2`.

If anyone can help me with this, will be grateful, thanks.

**EDIT**

NVM, solved with simpler method:

```
function printCategory($category, $html='', $level=0, $test=false) {
    $html .= '<ul>';
    if (count($category['children']) > 0) {
        $html .= '<li>' . $category['name'] . '</li>';
        foreach ($category['children'] as $c) {
            $html = printCategory($c, $html, $level, true);
        }
    }
    else {
        $html .= '<li>' . $category['name'] . '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a recursive function?

```
$output = "";

function iterate($array, &$output){
  $output .= “<ul>”;    
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(gettype($value) == “array”){
      iterate($value);
    } else {
      $output .= “<li>{$value}</li>";
    }
  }  
  $output .= “</ul>”;
}

iterate($array, $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems in the code is that you assume in the last `for` loop that once you are at a leaf-node, you should close the `ul` back right to the top-level, but this is not the case. You should only close the current `ul`, and let every instance of the recursive function call, deal itself with opening and closing its own `ul` tags.

Also, you have some code in the `if` that also occurs in the `else`, so just put that in the common part.

I was not sure want you intended to do with the *$space* variable, but I have re-used it for indenting the HTML tags, so that you can visually see the structure by looking at the produced HTML.

Here is the adapted code:

```
function printCategory($category, $html='', $space=0, $test=false) {
    $indent = str_repeat(" ", $space); // generate the spaces for indenting 
    $html .= "$indent<ul>\n"; // include the indenting in every "line"
    $html .= "$indent <li>" . $category['name'] . "</li>\n";
    // IF is not needed as for-loop will only execute if there are children
    foreach ($category['children'] as $c) {
        $html = printCategory($c, $html, $space + 1, true);
    }
    // always close just the one UL we opened at the start of this function.
    // the recursive calls will take care of their own UL tags.
    $html .= "$indent</ul>\n";

    return $html;
}
```

I used the above as follows to test it in a browser:

```
<?php
    $cats = array ( /* your first array */ );
    $html = htmlentities(printCategory($cats));
    echo "<pre>$html</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
 <li>category 1</li>
 <ul>
  <li>category 1 child</li>
  <ul>
   <li>category 1 grandchild</li>
   <ul>
    <li>category 1 great-grandchild</li>
   </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li>category 1 grandchild 2</li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li>category 1 child 2</li>
  <ul>
   <li>category 1 child 2 grandchild</li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</ul>
```